# How do you plot an SPL vs frequency curve for a given set of pressure data?

Tags: fft

I have a set of pressure data at a sampling rate of 262144 Hz for 3 seconds making it 786432 samples of pressure data. I want to plot a curve of the SPL (sound pressure level) vs frequency. I first converted pressure data to SPL using $20\log_{10}(P/P_{ref})$ and performed a 4096 point FFT for the 192 segments of data and averaged them.

However, I couldn't get the required SPL values in decibels. Was the approach correct? If not, could you please point out the mistake in my approach?

Comment: You will almost certainly want to do the FFT before you convert to decibels, not after.

Comment: However, this is not a programming question.  Once you know what maths you want to do, then programming it should be easy (if it's not, then ask a specific question).

Comment: programming is not an issue at all..so you want me to do a fft of the pressure data and then do the SPL calculations?

Answer (score 6):

The steps will be, in this order:

- apply [window function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function) (e.g. Hann or Hamming)
- calculate FFT
- calculate magnitude of FFT (`sqrt(re*re+im*im)`)
- convert magnitude to dB (`20*log10(magnitude)`)
- apply combined correction/calibration factors (window function compensation, FFT factor of N scaling if needed, factor of 2 for symmetric FFT, Pref calibration, etc) - this can just be a single dB correction value that you add to the dB magnitude values

If your Pref calibration data varies with frequency (e.g. microphone with non-flat frequency response) then it's a little more complicated than the above, but the same basic principles apply.

Note also that if you want weighted dB SPL (e.g. A weighting) then you'll also need to apply the relevant frequency dependent weighting corrections.

Comment: @Dilip Sarwate: yes, you can get rid of the `sqrt` and compensate for this in the dB calculation - note that I had a typo there previously - it's normally `20*log10(magnitude)` but of course you can just make this `10*log10(magnitude_squared)`. I deliberately didn't include this optimisation in the interest of clarity.